# Parallel building/deployment

Tags: shell, parallel-processing

I'm not sure what tags to put on this :

I have an Xcode project with multiple schemes that outputs multiple apps. I have a script `archive_all.sh` that is setting everything up to build and deploy (to TestFlight) each app (13 at the moment) by calling `archive.sh`. I tried (stupid me) to do : `sh archive.sh &` in the loop, but my laptop handled it hardly, and I plan to have much more than 13 apps to deployed in the future.

Is there a way, preferably in shell script to set up a queue of executable to call ? My laptop could probably handle 3-4 calls to `archive.sh` at a time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [ppss](http://code.google.com/p/ppss/) which supports both Linux and Mac OS X. It will auto-detect the number of cores in your CPU and execute tasks efficiently on those cores.

Answer (score 0):

GNU Parallel is made for these kind of jobs.

```
parallel archive.sh {} ::: app1 app2 ... app15
```

This will `archive.sh` for each app by running one per CPU core.

GNU Parallel is a general parallelizer and makes is easy to run jobs in parallel on the same machine or on multiple machines you have ssh access to.

If you have 32 different jobs you want to run on 4 CPUs, a straight forward way to parallelize is to run 8 jobs on each CPU:

[image: Simple scheduling]

GNU Parallel instead spawns a new process when one finishes - keeping the CPUs active and thus saving time:

[image: GNU Parallel scheduling]

**Installation**

If GNU Parallel is not packaged for your distribution, you can do a personal installation, which does not require root access. It can be done in 10 seconds by doing this:

```
(wget -O - pi.dk/3 || curl pi.dk/3/ || fetch -o - http://pi.dk/3) | bash
```

For other installation options see http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/parallel.git/tree/README

**Learn more**

See more examples: http://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/man.html

Watch the intro videos: https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL284C9FF2488BC6D1

Walk through the tutorial: http://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/parallel_tutorial.html

Sign up for the email list to get support: https://lists.gnu.org/mailman/listinfo/parallel